# RabbitTemplate not getting autowired in legacy project with older Spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement RabbitMQ in my old legacy project using plain spring.

I am trying to use like this :

```
@Autowire
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


public void send(){
    rabbitTemplate.ConvertAndSend("Hello")
}
```

But `rabbitTemplate` is getting as `null`.

Is there any alternative work around for this or I am missing something here ?

Comment: In order to autowire this, you will have needed to create a bean with the id "rabbitTemplate" in your Spring configuration file (xml) or configuration class (java class annotated with @Configuration). Can you share these if you have them?

Comment: An autowired field in spring cannot be `null`. So either you haven't enabled annotation processing in your xml (no `<context:component-scan />` or `<context:annotation-config />`) OR you are creating a new instance of this class yourself, which will lead to Spring not knowning about it and thus ignoring it.

Comment: I was actually instantiating the bean.*FacePalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo :** There is no such annotation in Spring called as `@Autowire`, it is `@Autowired`.

Please update to this :

```
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
```

That's why you are getting null.

Also, register the `RabbitTemplate` bean in the application context (XML config or java config).

**Follow this Spring + RabbitMQ implementation docs for well defined example with both XML config and java config:** https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/quick-tour.html

Comment: Well, it was typo. I followed your link and now I can send the message using the template. But listening message using @RabbitListener(queues = "MyQueue") does not work. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: here is the full description of my question and what i have implemented, please follow the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039093/java-springnot-spring-boot-rabbitmq-rabbitlistenerqueues-queue-does-not