# @RabbitListener(queues = "MyQueue") does not work in Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement rabbitmq in my **Spring** application, not spring boot.
So I added this configuration

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new Queue("MyQueue");
    }


}
```

Then from my service class I have used:-

```
public void sendViaTemplate(String msg){
        ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RabbitConfiguration.class);


        RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);

        template.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME,"Hello from template "+msg);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "MyQueue")
    public void ListenToMyQueue( String in){
        System.out.println("New Msg arrived"+in);
    }
```

The convertAndSend seems working as expected, but When the message is pushed into the queue, the ListenToMyQueue should be auto executed as new element is inserted into the queue, right? Why this is not working?

Answer (score -1):

For future refference, after many days of try, finally this listener configuration is working as expected. [enter link description here](https://www.javainuse.com/messaging/rabbitmq/listeners)

Comment: This is a spring boot solution, what should we do for a spring project not using spring boot ?